# Format Exception Unhandled while debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

When debugging the code, Visual Studio gives me a "format exception was unhandled" while highlighting this line of code: 'CustObj.d_CustDiscount = Convert.ToDecimal(gs_InPutBuffer.Substring(000, 004));'

I have been googling correct formats and have not come up with any fixes.  So my main question is, how do I rewrite this code in order for it to work?

Thanks for any help!

Below is the full program if you need to reference it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using CustFile_DLL;

namespace FileConvertorPA03
{
    class Program
    {
        //add these to handle I/O
        //instatiate streamreader
        private static StreamReader TextfileIn = new StreamReader("customers.txt");
        //instantiate the dll
        private static CustFileClass CustObj = new CustFileClass();
        //a few vars
        private static string gs_InPutBuffer = "";
        private static Int32 gi_TotalRec = 0, gi_FirstRecNo = 0;
        private static bool gb_FirstRec = true;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while ((gs_InPutBuffer = TextfileIn.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                ParsetoAttributes();
                CustObj.AddObject();
            }//end while
            PopMessageBox();
            TextfileIn.Close();
        }//end main

        //method to parse input buffer to class attributes
        private static void ParsetoAttributes()
        {
            CustObj.s_CustName = gs_InPutBuffer.Substring(000, 033).Trim();
            CustObj.s_CustAddress = gs_InPutBuffer.Substring(033, 032).Trim();
            CustObj.s_CustZip = gs_InPutBuffer.Substring(065, 005);
            CustObj.s_CustPhone = gs_InPutBuffer.Substring(070, 010);
            CustObj.d_CustDiscount = Convert.ToDecimal(gs_InPutBuffer.Substring(000, 004));
        }//end parse attributes

        //method to count records added
        static void CountRecs()
        {
            if (gb_FirstRec == true)
            {
                gi_FirstRecNo = CustObj.i_CustNumber;
                gb_FirstRec = false;
            }//end if 
            gi_TotalRec++;
        }//end count recs

        public static void PopMessageBox()
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Message: \n\tRecords Added \t{0,6}n\tFirst    Rec    Added\t     {1,6}\n\tLast   Rec  Added\t{2,6}",
            gi_TotalRec, gi_FirstRecNo, CustObj.i_CustNumber),"File Conversion Message:",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    }//end class
    }
}//end namespace
```

Comment: What is the value of gs_InPutBuffer.Substring(000, 004) at the time of conversion?

Comment: How would I go about checking that? I'm sorry I am very new to coding.

Comment: I would add a line right before the exception assigning to a variable, then you can set a breakpoint there and stop your code while debugging. This will allow you to see the value after calling substring(000, 004) by hovering over your new value after that line is executed but before the exception is thrown.

Comment: What would I make the line say?

Comment: var x = gs_InPutBuffer.Substring(000, 004); or whatever. It's just a way to find out the value by having in a variable. That should help you to figure out why you are getting a format exception when trying to convert it to a decimal by knowing what exactly you're trying to convert.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `ToDecimal` call with the following to find out what the issue is:

```
try
{
    CustObj.d_CustDiscount = Convert.ToDecimal(gs_InPutBuffer.Substring(0, 4));
}
catch (FormatException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(gs_InPutBuffer.Substring(0, 4));
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

If this isn't a console application, you can change the code in the catch block to write out to a `MessageBox`.  You can also leave out the leading zeros in the arguments to the calls to `Substring`.